# grabbing query string param in controller, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form within a blade that calls a controller function and I'm trying to wrap a url query string parameter into the function call.

the url is `testsite.com/verifyPhone?accessToken=1Kdfj348fDFJ$($kjdf`

In my controller function call I'm already using request for form validation

```
    $this->validate($request,[
        'verify_phone' => 'required',
    ]);
```

How can I grab the `accessToken` parameter in the URL as well and incorporate it into this request to send on my next call like so:

```
$authService->verifyPhone($request->accessToken, $request->verify_phone);
```

Comment: `$request->get('accessToken')` doesnt work?

Comment: shoot, I was using $request()->accessToken

Comment: i updated it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get the query parameter through the Input Facade

```
Input::get('accessToken')
```

Make sure to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input`

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantages of using Laravel is that you don't need to worry about preventing this kind of attack.

Laravel automatically handles it for each user session. You just need to include @csrf Blade directive in your form.

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? this has nothing to do with csrf, I'm getting a token from an internal API that is used for a feature registration. I just want to make sure I"m passing the url parameter called accessToken in this function call

Comment: I believe it's necessary to expect the question mark in your web.php route file.
Something like 

Route::get('/verifyPhone?accessToken={accessToken}'...

Comment: The param is there, but I'm not getting it at the route. Just in the controller. I'm just looking for something like request()->param

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$request->get('accessToken')
```

instead of

```
$request->accessToken
```